# Pokemon Go Evolving a Pokemon vs Catching it in the Wild

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a difference if I were to evolve a pidgey into a pidgeot vs catching a pidgeot in the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple.

The biggest one is that pokemon you evolve tend to have a higher CP than an already evolved pokemon in the wild but their maximum CP will always be the same. An exception would be if you evolved a pokemon when you're at level 5 but then you catch the same pokemon at level 10. Because your maximum CP for every pokemon is higher with trainer levels the pokemon you find also have higher CP.

The other reason is that you gain a fair amount of experience from evolving a pokemon. It is 500 experience per evolution and an extra 500 if the evolved pokemon is not something you have caught before.

Comment: But their maximum CP would be the same?  Then wouldn't it be better to just save the candy to power up the pidgeot instead of evovling?

Comment: yes. The Maximum CP would remain the same, they only change with an increase in Trainer level.

Comment: Evolving doesn't spend dust and powering up does. For something as common as pidgeys it is extremely easy to get pidgey candies while stardust is universal and should be treasured more.

Comment: I'm using pidgey as an example but for rare pokemons like Dragonites, it would be better to just save the candy to powerup than evovle a draginti?  Or Gradados, because 400 magickarp candies...........

Comment: Potentially yes but also keep in mind catching evolved form of pokemon is significantly harder especially for something as strong as Dragonite. Also stardust used for power ups gets very very expensive. Case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

I caught a Pigeoto and evolved a Pidgey but the wild one was still stronger; plus the wild one has better attacks. I do not understand it. Might as well evolve the wild Pigeoto at some point and just power up to max CP.